# how to get all/particular records from a table without using more than one sql query?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two drop lists and one grid view control. When the drop downs change I want those records to show in my grid. If "all" selected in any one of the drop down list or both then I want those records only. But I want the output without using different query for different conditions.

my code behind:

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select * from customers";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;User Id=sa;Password=");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            lblCountRows.Text = "Total Rows=" + dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + "";
        }

        private void BindDisposeId()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select distinct DisposeID from customers";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;User Id=sa;Password=");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            ddlDisposeID.DataTextField = "DisposeID";
            ddlDisposeID.DataValueField = "DisposeID";

            ddlDisposeID.DataSource = dt;
            ddlDisposeID.DataBind();
            ddlDisposeID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", ""));
        }

        private void BindReceiveId()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select distinct ReceiveID from customers";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;User Id=sa;Password=");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            ddlReceiveID.DataTextField = "ReceiveID";
            ddlReceiveID.DataValueField = "ReceiveID";

            ddlReceiveID.DataSource = dt;
            ddlReceiveID.DataBind();

            ddlReceiveID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", ""));
        }

        protected void DisposeIDchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlChanges();
        }

        protected void ReceiveIdchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlChanges();
        }

        private void ddlChanges()
        {
            string query = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            query = "SELECT C1.DisposeDate,C1.DisposeID,C1.ReceiveDate,C1.ReceiveID FROM Customers C1 LEFT JOIN Customers C2 ON C1.DisposeID=C1.ReceiveID where C1.DisposeID='" + ddlDisposeID.SelectedValue + "' AND C1.ReceiveID='" + ddlReceiveID.SelectedValue + "'";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;User Id=sa;Password=");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();            
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have done so far? Also try and explain slightly clearer what you've done and what you're after.

Comment: sorry i m bit lack in english but i ll try to make u clear as much as possible... my two dropdowns list are DisposeID and ReceiveID... i want to get all records in grid from the customers table when both the drop down indexes are "all".. if any one of the drop down selected value changed then i want that records to shown in my grid.....also if both the drop down selected value changed then that also shown in my grid.. but  i dont know how to use the above query for all these conditions i mentioned....( but i tried with using different query for different condition n got the desired output)...

Comment: Can you edit your original question with the "full" relevant code segments that relate to your query.

Comment: ya edited n i uploaded my full code above..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without fully understanding what you're specifically after. I will go on this assumption.

You have two parameters. `DisposeId` and `ReceiveId` coming from your drop down lists. You want to filter your query if both of those values are presented.

However, if none of the parameters are specified. You want to return `All` customers.

Personally, I would use a stored procedure to avoid using dynamic SQL. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROC up_Get_Customers
(
    @DisposeId INT,
    @ReceiveId INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT C1.DisposeDate,C1.DisposeID,C1.ReceiveDate,C1.ReceiveID
    FROM Customers C1 
    LEFT JOIN Customers C2 ON C1.DisposeID=C1.ReceiveID 
    WHERE (@DisposeId IS NULL OR C1.DisposeID= @DisposeId)
       AND (@ReceiveId IS NULL OR C1.ReceiveID= @ReceiveId)

END
```

In the query, I am saying that `WHEN` `@DisposeId` has not been specified, `THEN` just return all records. However, if it has been specified then return only the matching `DisposeId`. The same goes for `ReceiveId`.

So to return all records you would call the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC up_Get_Customers @DisposeId = NULL, @ReceiveId = NULL
```

If you want to return customers when values are specified, it would be:

```
EXEC up_Get_Customers @DisposeId = 1, @ReceiveId = 5
```

You could even specifiy a specific `DisposeId` but not `ReceiveId`. This will return all customers with a specified `DisposeId` but with any `ReceiveId` and vice versa.

```
--All DisposeIds for a specific ReceveId
EXEC up_Get_Customers @DisposeId = 1, @ReceiveId = NULL

--All ReceveIds for a specific DisposeId
EXEC up_Get_Customers @DisposeId = NULL, @ReceiveId = 5
```

Here is a (very basic) example of calling the stored procedure in your C# code:

```
private void ddlChanges()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;;User Id=sa;Password=admin@123");

            //Get the selected items from the dropdown lists
           var disposeId =  ddlDiposeId.SelectedValue.ToString() == "All" ? null : (int?)Convert.ToIn32(ddlDiposeId.SelectedValue);
           var receiveId = ddlReceiveId.SelectedValue.ToString() == "All" ? null :  (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlReceiveId.SelectedValue);

            //Create the two parameters for the stored procedures
            var sqlParameters = new []
                {
                    new SqlParameter("DisposeId", disposeId ?? (object)DBNull.Value),
                    new SqlParameter("ReceiveId", receivedId ?? (object)DBNull.Value)
                };

            //Create the SqlCommand.
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("up_Get_Customers", con);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                //Handle errors
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you thanks a lot.. i m new to sql.. little bit known about SP... yes.. this SP working fine... but i dont know how to used SP in code behind..

Comment: I've edited my answer. It will give you an idea of how to use the stored procedure in code.

Comment: thanks a lot bro...thanks a lot....

Comment: but got the error like, "operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'system.DBNull'" in the follwing lines                                                                               new SqlParameter("DisposeId", disposeId ?? DBNull.Value),
                    new SqlParameter("ReceiveId", receivedId ?? DBNull.Value)....

Comment: Ah yes. is your ddlDisposeId.SelectedValue always number? If so, you just need to convert the value to an int. I've added some extra code to my answer. Basically, when you add the SqlParameters. You either need to specify the INT value of the Dispose/ReceiveId. If one isn't selected, you just need to make it DBNull.Value. I've updated my answer to show you.

Comment: yes.. my both id's are always number... i convert both the value to int32.. still error existing...

Comment: They must still be strings though as the error says that it "cannot use ?? with strings". Try debugging the app and set a breakpoint on the line SqlParameter("DisposeId", disposeId ?? DbNull.Value) and check to see what type the variable disposeId is. It should be an int. Just realised it needs to be a 'nullable' into as well 'int?' So that it can check for the null value.

Comment: Yes. Both ids are strings. How can I change them to int. I tried many things nothing works. Help me.

Comment: Please see updated answer. It will check to see if 'ReceiveId' or 'DiposeId' is "All" if so, it sets the value to NULL. Then  the SqlParameter value must be cast as (object)DBNull.Vaue if the value was null. Please ensure you've done exactly as what's in my answer otherwise it will not work.

Comment: still getting error in line "var receiveId = ddlReceiveID.SelectedValue.ToString() == "All" ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlReceiveID.SelectedValue);" as input string was not in correct format.

Comment: This must mean that ddlReceiveId.SelectedValue is either not "All" or is not a valid number. Use your IDE's debugger and step through the code, add a break point on the line and see what the "SelectedValue" actually is.

Comment: i am selected 2 in disposeid dropdown.. after debugging i have some results as, disposeid.selectedvalue=2 and its type is string... then receivedid.selectedvalue="" and type is also string... but  disposeid=2 and its type is int? and same here as well receiveid=null and type is int?... i dont know what is mean by "int?" and that line shows error as i mentioned above...

Comment: finally got the output... its my mistake man... in my code, "All"'s value field i set as ""... but so far i m using value field as "All"... working now... thanks for your response though i m new to stack overflow and having lack of english...thanks again....

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. Happy coding!

Comment: one more question., for an example, consider i have those dropdown lists with multiple check boxes.  i m checking one or more values ... then what will be the query or SP?

Comment: You will need to raise a new question on stackoverflow and then we can help you.

Comment: they put me on hold.i cant raise a question for 2 more days.